# Getting undefined method error in ruby on rails while the method is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my ruby on rails app, when I change my code (for example change line 5 from `i = f1` to `i = f2` I get this error :

> NoMethodError in Api::V1::AppController#login
> undefined method `f2' for #Master::Utilities:0x00007fdb6ceb42c8

this is my code

```
class Api::V1::AppController < ApplicationController

  def login
    c = Master::Utilities.new
    i = c.f1
    z = c.f2
    render json: {m: 'login' , msg: "hello" , data: "#{z} - #{i}" } , status: :ok
  end
end
```

undoing the change doesn't solve the problem.
after getting this error I **restart** Puma and everything gets **ok again** without changing code.

these are my codes

- lib\master\utilities.rb

  ```
  module Master
    class Utilities
    Dir[File.join(__dir__, 'code', '*.rb')].each { |file| require file }
    end
  end
  ```
- lib\master\code\1.rb

  ```
  module Master
    class Utilities
        def f1
            "Function 1"
        end 
    end
  end
  ```
- lib\master\code\2.rb

  ```
  module Master
    class Utilities
        def f2
            "Function 2"
        end 
    end
  end
  ```

I use this code in `config\application.rb` to autoload my code

```
  config.paths.add Rails.root.join('lib').to_s, eager_load: true
```

I'm new to ruby on rails and I think that I have a small mistake in my code but I can't find where.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going wrong here is that when you edit the file, rails sees the call to `Master::Utilities.new`  and re-loads the definition of `Master::Utilities`. But when it gets to this part:

```
Dir[File.join(__dir__, 'code', '*.rb')].each { |file| require file }
```

...It sees that, for example, `lib/master/code/1.rb` has *already been loaded*. (`require` doesn't reload files that are already loaded!).

Therefore none of the method definitions are being defined, and so effectively you end up with a `Master::Utilities` class with no instance methods.

---

A quick, *minimal* fix would be to replace the above `require` with `load`, to explicitly say "always load the file, even if it was loaded before":

```
Dir[File.join(__dir__, 'code', '*.rb')].each { |file| load file }
```

---

However, I'd point out that this is a very unusual way to structure the code in ruby/rails; and you'd probably benefit more from following a more conventional approach.

What benefit/logic is there in splitting a single class' definition into multiple files? If you want to go looking for where a method is defined, wouldn't it be easier to either have them all in one place, or to split them into logical **modules**?

If you follow the convention of "only define the class in one place, and make the class name match the file name", then eager loading in rails will work smoothly out of the box. For example, you could perhaps do:

```
# lib/master/utilities.rb
module Master
  class Utilities
    def f1
      # ...
    end

    def f2
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Or:

```
# lib/master/utilities/meaningful_name_1.rb
module Master
  module Utilities
    class MeaningFulName1
      def f1
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end

# lib/master/utilities/meaningful_name_2.rb
module Master
  module Utilities
    class MeaningFulName2
      def f2
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Or if you *really* want to have all methods in one huge class, with automatic loading of all files in a folder (even though that sounds very disorganised to me!), you could write some meta-programming - e.g. using `String#classify` to convert the filenames to their module names.

Comment: The reason I want to split code is that every function I use has at least 50 lines of comment (my code is actually a bridge between my app and external REST API. it processes my data and send them to External API and reverse . each function uses an external rest API and everything about API Payload and response is documented with sample) and the second reason is each function maybe developed and maintained by a different developer so I thought this method is better to organize code and increase readability (have multiple small files instead of a very large file) . Thanks for your help again 

Comment: You could also define methods within `Master::Utilities` that merely delegate to a "function" which is defined elsewhere, e.g.`Master::Utilities#f1` could invoke `Master::Functions::F1.call(...)`. This way, you can have all methods (`f1`, `f2` etc) in on place while keeping their (huge) implementations in separate files.